# @OneToOne is eagerly fetched when entity with @OneToOne is fetched by join fetch

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have the following 3 classes:

```
public class Object {
    ...whatever
}

public class CustomerObject {

    @OneToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "OBJECT_ID", referencedColumnName = "OBJECT_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)  
    private Object object;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CUSTOMER_TYPE_ID", referencedColumnName = "OBJECT_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private CustomerTypeObject customerTypeObject;

}

public class CustomerTypeObject {

    @JoinColumn(name = "OBJECT_ID", referencedColumnName = "OBJECT_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @OneToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Object object;

}
```

When I do this:

```
entityManager.createQuery(
"select cust from CustomerObject cust "
+ "left join fetch cust.customerTypeObject customerType "
+ "where cust.id = :customer_id 
, CustomerObject.class)
.setParameter("customer_id", BigDecimal.valueOf(1))
.getSingleResult();
```

Hibernate is issueing 1 query to get customer with its customerType, but then it is also issueing query to get Object association in CustomerTypeObject entity. Issue is resolved (i.e. only one query is issued) by join fetching that association:

```
entityManager.createQuery(
"select cust from CustomerObject cust "
+ "left join fetch cust.customerTypeObject customerType "
+ "left join fetch customerType.object customerTypeObject "
+ "where cust.id = :customer_id 
, CustomerObject.class)
.setParameter("customer_id", BigDecimal.valueOf(1))
.getSingleResult();
```

but I don't want to do this. Is there no way to do this? (i.e. do not eagerly fetch OneToOne association in an entity that is already join fetched in a query).

Comment: Do you know this blog post? https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/best-practices-many-one-one-many-associations-mappings/

Comment: I've just read that, but it doesn't answer my question at all. I think what I wrote in question is pretty clear.